# Disabling checkbox using KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

I am unable to disable the checkbox when the length of observable array reaches a specific limit.
Here is the link to code : http://jsfiddle.net/pLNdc/59/

```
<ul class="options" data-bind="foreach: choices">
<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers"
    data-bind="attr: { value: $data },
               checked: $parent.selectedChoices,
               enable: $parent.selectedChoices.length < 2" />
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></label></li>
</ul>
<hr />
```

```
var viewModel = {};

viewModel.choices = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
viewModel.selectedChoices = ko.observableArray(["two", "four"]);

viewModel.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    return viewModel.selectedChoices().join(",");
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `selectedChoices` is an observable, you need to call it with parens before accessing its `length` property, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="NotifyMembers"
       data-bind="attr: { value: $data },
                  checked: $parent.selectedChoices,
                  enable: $parent.selectedChoices().length < 2" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ismail. 
Just want to add little more to existing code. I can now disable the checkbox. But now i want is to disable only the checkboxes that are only unchecked.

Comment: @Sabby62 Something like `enable: $parent.selectedChoices.indexOf($data) !== -1 || $parent.selectedChoices().length < 2`

Comment: @Sabby62 Although at that point I'd extract that logic out into a method on the view model.